Schur complement unambiguous notation
As I understand it, the normal notation for the Schur complement of $M$ w.r.t. $A$, $M/A$ is ambiguous.  Specifically, "/" isn't an operation on two matrices; the meaning of the second matrix is to specify a position rather than a matrix value, but the notation contains its value rather than its position.
For example, consider the matrix $$M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}$$ from Wikipedia.  Let $A = D = I$.  Then $M/I = M/D = A - BD^{-1}C = I - BC$, but also $M/I = M/A = D - C A^{-1}B = I - CB$.
Unless $B$ and $C$ commute, these are different, and so  $$\begin{pmatrix} I & B \\ C & I \end{pmatrix}/ I$$ is ambiguous.
The only way to write $M/A$ unambiguously is to accompany it by an unambiguous statement of where $A$ is within the matrix, rather than just specifying the value of $A$.
Is there unambiguous notation for the Schur complement, specifying the rows and columns to remove, rather than their content?
One option would be $M/\{\text{set of rows columns to remove}\}$, but that is messy if we want a statement that holds for different block sizes, unless there is standard notation for "the number of columns of $A$".

Did you check wikipedia? there is no ambiguity if you properly partition your block matrix

Thanks for getting back to me.  Yes, I did read Wikipedia.  I've updated the example to be the one on that page.
